# HttpWebRequest sometimes incorrectly decoding parts of a query parameter

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

I have spotted something which seems off in the HttpWebRequest object.

If I run the following:

```
var q = "кот (";
```

(Note here 'кот' is written in Russian, apparently it means cat.)

```
 var encoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(q);
 var url = $"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&include_entities=true&q={encoded}";
```

I get the following value in url:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&include_entities=true&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%20%28
```

If I then run this:

```
var r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
r.GetResponse();
```

In Fiddler, the above is observed to actually make a request:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&include_entities=true&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%20(
```

Note that the ( is not encoded as %28 as it was when I constructed the HttpWebRequest.

If instead I use:

```
q = "CAT ("
```

i.e. no Russian characters, only latin(?), I get this as the URL:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&include_entities=true&q=CAT%20%28
```

And this is *also* the request observed in Fiddler.

To summarise, it seems when *mixing* latin and non latin characters, the ( is not being sent encoded.

Does anybody have any suggestions how to solve this?

UPDATE:
This is important because as far as I can tell it is the reason I can't successfully make these API queries to Twitter as it appears to be breaking our OAuth1 signing, we are getting:
HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

I can even edit the failing request in Fiddler and replace the ( with a %28 in the GET request, and it then succeeds on replaying it with this single change.

Answer (score 0):

This may help... it appears that the behaviour of the Uri class is as follows:

```
var q = "кот (";

var encoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(q);
// encoded = %D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%20%28

var uri = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&include_entities=true&q=" + encoded);
// uri.AbsoluteUri = https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&include_entities=true&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%20(

var uri2 = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&include_entities=true&q=CAT (");
// uri2.AbsoluteUri = https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&include_entities=true&q=CAT%20(

var uri3 = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&include_entities=true&q=кот (");
// uri3.AbsoluteUri = https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100&include_entities=true&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%20(
```

I cannot debug into the .NET Framework code at the moment, but I suspect use of Uri.EscapeDataString might be incorrect WRT non-Latin chars and brackets?

Does the request with the unencoded bracket actually work? If so I would suggest the bracket does not need encoding...

UPDATE: I actually think this might be a bug in Uri?

Comment: I also currently suspect this is a bug in .NET / the Uri class.